# Is there anything like Macro (#define) in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, macros, inline

I'm writing a program that contains a lot of similar lines of code, like below :

```
If Bird.Left + Bird.Width - Wall1.Left < 2 And Bird.Left + Bird.Width - Wall1.Left > -2 And Bird.Top > Wall1.Top Then
```

and

```
 If Bird.Left + Bird.Width - Wall2.Left < 2 And Bird.Left + Bird.Width - Wall2.Left > -2 And Bird.Top > Wall2.Top Then
```

and some other lines just like this, Is there any way to declare these similar lines as for example f(x,y) without using functions ? (Because writing a function for this slows down the program a lot)

Comment: "because writing a function for this slows down the program a lot" what evidence do you have to back this up? A function is more than likely going to be quick enough.

Comment: Why do you think using a function slows it down? By the way, you probably want to use `AndAlso` instead, to improve performance a shade.

Comment: because this lines are in a timers tick event that happens every 1/1000 seconds and calling a lot of  functions every 1/1000 seconds slows down the program

Comment: @AppDeveloper He's looking for macros.

Comment: yes exactly I'm looking for macros

Comment: @Navid777 - how about inline function ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14384737/922198

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally in .NET 4.5, the CLR allows one to force method inlining using [`MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) value. It is also available in the Mono's trunk (committed today).